# Can all subspaces of a vector space form a vector space?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $S$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. Can all subspaces of $S$ form a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, which treats each $S$'s subspace as an element? The elements of the new vector space should also be (or representations of) subspaces of $S$.

Someone told me "Think about $\mathbb{R}^3$. You have a single 0-dimensional subspace, and a single 3-dimensional subspace, and two real projective planes of 1-dimensional and 2-dimensional subspaces. Topologically, not a vector space."

Comment: You may wish to look up the Grassmannian space.

Comment: Can they form a vector space? Absolutely! If the vector space is finite-dimensional, then the subspaces can be put into bijection with $\Bbb{R}$, and we can use this to define horrific operations that will make this a one-dimensional vector space. If you want something more natural (where summing subspaces will be compatible in some way with vector sums), that's potentially a more interesting question, but I suspect you won't get a nice vector space construction.

Comment: @JoseAvilez, I hope that the new vector space has elements that are susbspaces of $S$

Comment: @TheoBendit, I need the elements of the new vector space are also the subspaces of$S$.

Comment: @John I understand, but I'm saying you almost certainly won't get "nice" operations. Indeed, I forgot to think about the one dimensional case, in which case it's impossible, since there are no real vector space with two vectors. In higher dimensional real spaces, it's possible, but you won't get anything that anyone would like to work with.

Comment: @TheoBendit, someone told me: "Think about $\mathbb{R}^3$. You have a single 0-dimensional subspace, and a single 3-dimensional subspace, and two real projective planes of 1-dimensional and 2-dimensional subspaces. Topologically, not a vector space." I don't so understand it. Can you help with it?

Comment: @John Perhaps. I'm a little light on time at the moment, but I might come back later and try explaining it. For now, I would advise editing this comment into the body of your question, because it seems to me that this is the true issue you want to deal with. Also, are you familiar with any topology? You don't necessarily need to be; it just would be some good context to include in your question.

Comment: Thanks @TheoBendit

Comment: IIRC, someone else asked [almost the same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4196376/can-vector-subspaces-be-elements-of-another-non-trivial-vector-space) four days ago....

Comment: Also posted to (and closed on) MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/397718/can-all-subspaces-of-a-vector-space-form-a-vector-space

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can vector subspaces be elements of another non-trivial vector space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4196376/can-vector-subspaces-be-elements-of-another-non-trivial-vector-space)

Answer (score 2):

It's worth looking at [Andrew's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4196376/can-vector-subspaces-be-elements-of-another-non-trivial-vector-space), as he goes into this question in some detail. I do suspect, though, that his answer might be a little technical for your taste.

The short answer to your main question is, yes, in most cases (when reals are the scalars) it is technically possible. I'd like to emphasise the weasel word "technically" as much as humanly possible here. I doubt you'd find a single person, on this entire site, who would be willing to work out an explicit formulation of the subspaces of even $\Bbb{R}^3$ (or $\Bbb{R}^2$) as a vector space. I'm not sure that such a person exists in the entire world.

The operations you'd get would be totally unnatural; trying to work with such a space would, instead of illuminating something interesting about the structure of the subspaces, would just cloud everything under layer upon layer of pointless, arbitrary computation. Trying to better understand subspaces through such a space would be like trying to understand sorting algorithms by [repeatedly playing 52 pickup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort) with a deck of cards: it would be a frustrating waste of time, and you'd be none the wiser about the topic you were trying to learn about.

The fact is, subspaces are just not *naturally* a vector space. It's not totally unreasonable to think they might be. Finite-dimensional vector spaces have enormous amounts of structure, and we already have, inbuilt into the definition, ways to sum vectors and multiply vectors by a scalar. And, our subspaces are just spans of finite collections of vectors, which we are perfectly capable of summing and scaling. All the right ingredients are there. Can we figure something out?

Let's observe some facts:

- Bases are instantly tricky to work with, because finite-dimensional, non-trivial real vector spaces have infinitely many of them. If you were to naively suggest that, maybe, that the sum of two-dimensional spaces $\operatorname{span}(v, w)$ and $\operatorname{span}(p, q)$ ought to be $\operatorname{span}(v + p, w + q)$, then this is a problem because the resulting subspace **depends on the choice of bases**. That is, the sum isn't a sum of *subspaces* so much as it is a sum of bases (and the result need not even be linearly independent). Even swapping the order of the vectors in one of the bases will generally produce a different sum!
- If you scale vectors in a subspaces, the result is still in the subspaces. So, no matter how you scale any collection of vectors in your subspace, you're never going to escape your subspace. This suggests heavily that if your scaling operation on the vector space of subspaces were to have *anything at all* to the usual vector scalar multiplication, then scaling will do *nothing* to the subspace (except, maybe, the $0$ scalar). The vector space axioms don't allow this; scaling a non-zero vector will produce a different vector for each scalar you use.
- If you were thinking of using the nice and already established sum of subspaces: $$W_1 + W_2 = \{w_1, w_2 : w_1 \in W_1, w_2 \in W_2\},$$
  then this will not work, as it fails the cancellation law in general. That is, it is possible to have subspaces $A, B, C$ of a vector space $V$ such that $A + C = B + C$, but have $A \neq B$. For example, $V = \Bbb{R}^2$, $A$ is the $x$-axis, $B$ is the $y$-axis, and $C$ is the diagonal line $\operatorname{span}\{(1, 1)\}$. The sums $A + C$ and $B + C$ will be all of $\Bbb{R}^2$, but $A$ and $B$ are clearly different. If this addition were the addition in a vector space, then this cancellation property would hold, by additive identity and inverse axioms.

Can we just get more creative in how we sum subspaces? Well, yes, as I mentioned before, it is possible with a fair amount of creativity, to create these operations. But, the more creativity we need to use, the less comprehensible it will be to us mere mortals. At some point, you have to leave usefulness behind.

This "topological" comment that someone made to you is another way of thinking about it. While you didn't ask for any kind of topology or norm, or other analytic structure, it's not unreasonable to expect one. You can imagine, for example, smoothly transitioning one plane to another in $\Bbb{R}^3$, simply rotating the plane. This intuitive idea of "smooth transition" suggests that some subspaces are closer than others. And indeed, when we consider a topology (very roughly speaking, a notion of "nearness" between points) on a vector space that is "compatible" with its operations, we tend to find that the space is "connected" (or more technically, "path-connected"), meaning that any point in the space can be smoothly transitioned to another.

What about subspaces of $\Bbb{R}^3$? Well, not so much. Can you think of a way, intuitively speaking, you could smoothly morph a plane into a line? Or maybe a a line to the trivial space? Or even the full space? All the lines and all the planes seem "separate" from each other in a sense; one would have to make a significant leap in order to move from the set of lines to the set of planes, or vice-versa. Vector spaces with good topologies cannot have these separate little cliques like this; they all need to be connected as part of the same fabric, which again suggests that there is no nice way to turn the set of subspaces into a vector space.

All that said, subspaces do have a natural kind of structure. As Jose Avilez points out right up the top, you should look up [Grassmannians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmannian). These are the natural topological structures that subspaces form. They are not vector spaces, but compact, smooth manifolds. They form a curve or a (hyper)surface, on which there is sufficient structure to perform calculus. It's not quite as nice a vector space, but it's the best you'll do while the structure remains remotely comprehensible.

Answer (score 1):

If one interprets the question more broadly, asking whether it is possible to construct a geometrically meaningful vector space such that vector subspaces of $S$ can be considered to be its elements,
then the exterior algebra $ΛS$ of $S$ comes pretty close to fulfilling such a demand.

Specifically, one can define the exterior algebra of $S$ as the commutative graded algebra generated by generators $(V,v)$ in degree $\dim V$,
where $V$ is a vector subspace of $S$ and $v$ is an oriented volume
element on $V$.
Over real numbers, an oriented volume element can be defined
as pair consisting of an orientation of $V$ and a translation-invariant Radon measure on $V$.

Then one must impose a few relations on these generators:

- the product $(V,v)∧(W,w)$ vanishes if $V∩W≠\{0\}$ and otherwise
  equals $(V+W,v⊗w)$;
- for a real number $r$, we have $r(V,v)=(V,rv)$, where $rv$ multiplies the oriented volume element $v$ by $r$ (in terms of translation-invariant Radon measures, the measure must be divided by $r≠0$);
- if $\dim V=\dim W=1$, then (identifying $v$ and $w$ with an element of $V$ respectively $W$ in this case) $(V,v)+(W,w)=(\mathop{\rm Span}(v+w),v+w)$.

The resulting algebra satisfies the universal property of exterior algebras, so is isomorphic to any of the more traditional constructions.

This presentation comes pretty close to giving an answer to the question, modulo two points:

- A vector subspace $V$ of $S$ should be equipped with an oriented volume element $v$;
- The sum of $(V,v)$ and $(W,w)$ need not be representable in the form $(X,x)$ for some vector subspace $X$ of $S$, i.e., not all elements in the Grassmann algebra are decomposable.